# How do I prevent my iMac from blocking an incoming screen sharing connection?

Tags: network, vpn, sharing

I have a MBP (2016, running 12.6.8) and an iMac, (M1 2021, running 13.5.2). I can screen share (using the built in app) from the iMac to the MBP via local area connection and via a DDNS. However, when I try to screen share from my MBP to the iMac (i.e. sharing the iMac screen), the iMac seems to be blocking the incoming connection.

I have exactly mirrored the sharing settings on each computer, including turning all firewalls off. File sharing/SMB works perfectly, bidirectionally. I don't have any VPN settings etc active. Error message states: Unable to communicate with "iMac". Make sure the remote computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing. In finder, on the MBP, the screen sharing icon in available in top right.

If I turn off screen sharing on the iMac, this icon disappears and reappears when I turn screen sharing back on. It's clear the connection is available, but it seems to be blocked. My last resort would be a clean install but I thought it best to source ideas/anything I've missed first. Thanks.

Comment: What does DDNS have to do this?  Screen sharing is not related to this at all.  Can you make a shared screen connection  using just IP addresses on your local network?

Comment: @Allan - No, MBP -> iMac cannot be shared locally (i.e. using vnc://192.xxx.x.xxx). The iMac -> MBP can. I also used a DDNS hosting service to access iMac -> MBP outside my network (being the ultimate point of this exercise, but with MBP -> iMac).